# Does Rails 3 have find_by association magic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Specifically, let's assume that we have two sensible models:

1. `TieDyeCentipede`, which `has_many :legs`
2. `Leg`, which has a `:color` attribute.

Being a `TieDyeCentipede`, no two legs are ever the same color. In fact, a particular leg's color is unique among **all** of the legs of all of our `TieDyeCentipedes`.

Based on that uniqueness, we want to find a particular `Centipede` by a particular color of leg -- let's say `:deep_sky_blue`.

I could do something like:

`critter = Leg.find_by_color(:deep_sky_blue).tie_dye_centipede`

However, is there a `find_by_*` method on the `TieDyeCentipede` class that I could use as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No magic:

```
TieDyeCentipede.joins(:legs).where(:legs => {:color => 'deep_sky_blue'}).first
```

Some magic:

```
def self.find_by_leg_color(color)
  TieDyeCentipede.joins(:legs).where(:legs => {:color => color}).first
end
```

Comment: Rats! Well, thank you for the answer. I was hoping it had some built-in magic!

Answer (score 3):

Try `TieDyeCentipide.joins(:legs).where(:legs => {:color => :deep_sky_blue}).first`

For a `find_by_*` method or something similar, I'd recommend [Pacecar](https://github.com/thoughtbot/pacecar), which generates many useful scopes for your AR models.